# 32 bit v/s 64 bit

Tags: hardware, cpu-architecture

I have a small confusion.
When we talk about 32-bit architecture and 64-bit architecture what do we actually mean. Do we mean that a 32 bit architecture has 32 bit registers OR 32 bit address-bus OR 32-bit data bus.

What is generally implied?

Comment: Also, 64-bit CPU and ALU architectures are those that are based on registers, address buses, or data buses of that size. 64-bit is also a term given to a generation of computers in which 64-bit processors are the norm. - **Wiki**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! Thanks a lot for your inputs.
After reading through a lot of articles and online material, I think now I my confusion is no more. 
So I would like to briefly summarize.
**n-bit CPU:**

An n-bit CPU only means that it has n-bit registers which implies an n-bit word size. Don't give a second thought on address/data bus size.

As an example, consider Motorola 68000 processor - which comes in a 32-bit variant ie it is called a 32-bit processor but it has 16-bit data bus and 24-bit address bus. Due to its 24-bit address bus, it can address only 2^24 ie 16 MB of RAM.
Address bus only tells how much RAM can be addressed whereas data bus tells how many units of data can be transferred in one cycle.
68000 processor can thus transact only 2 Bytes of data due to 16 bits in data bus.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that *usually*, this would mean that a 64-bit system has 64-bit address registers. In modern systems, data registers are usually at least as large as the address registers, so the data registers and data bus would likely be equivalently sized.

A 64-bit system, however, usually does *not* have a 64-bit address bus. There's no point, since there hasn't been enough RAM manufactured in the history of the planet to need a full 64 bit physical address bus. A given system will have a maximum amount of physical RAM that it can address, based on the width of its address bus.

Comment: OK. Lets talk about 32-bit architecture. Will this have 32-bit data bus in addition to 32-bit address bus. ??

Comment: Most 32-bit systems today have a full 32-bit address bus (because 4 GB of RAM is not unusual). However, this was not always the case (I'm sure my first 80386 system did not have a 32 bit address bus!).

Comment: Yes, earlier processors had some additional segment registers. But speaking of today, if someone talks about 32-bit architecture. can we imply that it would have 32-bit address and data bus or it means just 32-bit address bus.

Comment: You imply that data bus width tends to match register width.  In systems with caches that's often not the case.  Often you have wider buses than GP-integer registers.

Answer (score 0):

We mean that we have 64 bit of address space for programs.

This usually means that we have 64 bit registers in the CPU (makes sense to have the registers in pointer size) and so on...

Answer (score 0):

a 32 bit architecture means that the ALU [(description)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) is capable of computing 32-bit words. The databus (width) and the registers are included in this definition, as well as adressing.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the registers and stack (!) have a width of 32/64 bits. Address-spaces are often much smaller, see here:

> In principle, a 64-bit microprocessor can address 16 exabytes of memory. In practice, it is less than that.
>
> For example, the AMD64 architecture as of 2011 allows 52 bits for physical memory and 48 bits for virtual memory.

[wikipedia-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit)